# How to display a preview of file from local storage in a react native component?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am working on a App in which there's an upload button through which user can select a file to be sent to the server. But before the file is send i would like to display a preview of the file below the upload button. How can that be implemented? I don't want to preview it separately.. It should be visible below the upload button inside a react native component.

Comment: What type of file you're trying to show up ?

Comment: Any type of document.. Pdf, txt, sheets etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, you are using this package **react-native-image-picker**.

```
const handleCaptureImage = () => {
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker({
      title: 'Take picture',
      chooseFromLibraryButtonTitle: 'Choose picture from gallery',
  
    }, response => {
      if (response.didCancel) {
          
      } else if (response.error) {
          console.log(response.error)
      } else {
          let source = { uri: response.uri };
          let data = {
              source: source,
              response: response,
              taken:true,
              mode:0 // For Image Capture
          };
          setimageURI(data);
      }
  });
   }

<Image
        source={imageURI.source}
        style={_._dpcontainer}
        resizeMode='contain'
      />
```

Even if you are not using this library. The way to show any image. You need to get its URI

Then,

In Image Component (React)

You can show it like this,

```
<Image source={{uri: YOUR IMAGE URI}}/>
```

Comment: is there a way to open a pdf or text file in the app ? on a new screen or maybe component?

Answer (score 0):

For displaying an image is pretty simple, you can have a state to store the image or pdf details once you have uploaded it.

To display the image,
`<Image source={{uri: imageUrl}}/>` // which you stored in state

To display a pdf, you can use `react-native-view-pdf` package,

**ViewPdf.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import Pdf from 'react-native-view-pdf';

export type Props = {
    imageUrl: string,
    imageName: string,
    styles: object
}

const ViewPdf: React.FC<Props> = ({
    imageUrl,
    imageName,
    styles
}) => {
    const source = { uri: imageUrl, cache: true };
    return(
        <View style = {{flex: 1}}>
            <Pdf resource={imageUrl} style={styles} fadeInDuration={100}/>
        </View>
    )
};

export default ViewPdf;
```

and call it as:

```
<ViewPdf 
     imageUrl = {uri} 
     imageName = {fileName} 
     styles = {styles.thumbnail_image}
 />
```

Comment: and what about other documents?

Comment: then you can go with  **react-native-file-viewer**. You can view any types of file. You can use the same structure as given above.

Comment: okay thank you for your quick response. Just one more thing, is there a way to view file from remote URL without downloading them?

Comment: A webview might be useful there.

Comment: yes  I have used webView only...but it loads the pdf sometimes and sometimes just a blank screen.